# Combining Lists of Multiple Dataframes in R

Tags: r

For simplicity, I have made the following code.

```
 df1 <- data.frame(A=c(1:3), B=c('A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B'))
 df2 <- data.frame(C=c('D'), D=c(4, 4, 5, 5, 6, 6))
 one <- split(df1, df1$B)
 two <- split(df2, df2$D)
 goal_df <- data.frame(A=c(1:3), B=c('A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B'),
                  C=c('D'), D=c(4, 4, 5, 5, 6, 6))
```

I have two lists like 'one' and 'two'. This lists contain several thousand data frames. I want to combine all of these into one data frame. I tried rbind, but I ran into issues because the dimensions of the data frames in the list vary. The end result should be what I have called goal_df

Comment: Just do `cbind(do.call(rbind, one), do.call(rbind, two))`

Comment: When I used this on my actual code I received the following error: error in data.frame(..., check.names = FALSE) arguments imply differing number of rows: 30, 18

Comment: Can you try with the code I posted as a solution.  Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use

```
library(rowr)
do.call(cbind.fill, c(list(do.call(rbind, one), do.call(rbind, two)), fill = NA))
```

Comment: That worked, any idea why this worked and the first solution did not?

Comment: @Jordan The reason is that the two datasets created with `do.call(rbind` have unequal number of rows, so when you `cbind`, it creates the error you described.  WIth `cbind.fill`, it will fill those extra rows with the `fill` argument that is passed i.e. `NA` here

Comment: That makes sense. Thank you for your help